# How to capture angular JavaScript errors using event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror, addeventlistener, angular-promise

We want to capture these two errors using JavaScript

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'big' of undefined
at t.brokenCode (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1
at Uo (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at s (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at l.invokeTask (polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)



ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'big' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'big' of undefined
at t.brokenCode (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at t.n (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at next (<anonymous>)
at main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1
at new C (polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js:1)
at t.brokenAsyncCode (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1
at Uo (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at s (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.6e3ef82a1a9a4d77938a.js:1)
at Z (polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js:1)
```

we are using event handlers to capture these errors like bellow

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
console.log("error"+event);
});

window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (event) {
console.log("unhandledrejection"+event);
 });
```

but these events are not get trigger for these two errors,
so how can we capture these errors?

we have these two functions:

```
brokenCode(): void { 
const something = 'DataInfo'; 
const bar = something + 0; 
bar.toString()[33].big(); 
} 

 async brokenAsyncCode(): Promise<void> { 
return Promise.resolve(this.brokenCode()); 
}
```

Note:
angular version: 12

The event listener are not able to capture the angular  Jserror due to the Zone.js
because zone js has modify the event listener to achieve change detection for angular.

So that I have tried to blacklist the error  event before loading the zone js,
but still not able to capture an error using event listener...

we only want to handle these error using any event handler.

Thanks...

Comment: It looks like you can produce these errors (`brokenCode` and `brokenAsyncCode`) - please provide the code in question

Comment: `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection'` probably

Comment: "unhandledrejection" event also not get trigger for both the errors

Comment: Are you sure the error happens in the same document as where you try to capture it? Not in a frame or worker? Best would be of course to properly manage errors at each promise you use...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the AngularJS native `$exceptionHandler`?

You can register this service as a factory on your module and catch any unhandled exceptions. [Check the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) and see if this solution is adequate for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to capture an event using window Event Listener, like if I add  Event Listener at browser console, so that it has to trigger these errors..